# Header & Nav tags not working properly in 11 IE after deployment

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a problem with the HTML elements in IE after I deployed it to the server when I inspect the elements in all browser like Chrome, IE, and so on, it appears like the below order

```
<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

```
<header class="header header-v1">
            <div class="logo">
            <a href="Home.html"><img src="images/Header/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image"></a>
            </div><!-- End Logo -->
            <nav class="navi-desktop-site">
                <ul class="navi-level-1">
                    <li class="has-sub p1"><a>Home<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="navi-level-2 ">
                            <li><a href="#" >Tes1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Tes2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">More +</a></li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    
                        <li class="has-sub p1"><a>Contact Us<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="navi-level-2 ">
                            <li><a href="#" >Email</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >More +</a></li>
                        
                        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav> <!-- End Navi Desktop -->
            <div class="navi-right">


                <div title="library" class="circle-wrapper">
                    <div class="lib circle"></div>
                    <div class="icon">
                    </div>
                </div>
         

            </div>
        </header><!-- END HEADER -->
```

once I deployed the page to the server, the style was not working properly then I tried to inspect the elements in the 11 IE, I found it appears as below code

```
<header class="header header-v1"></header>
   <nav class="navi-desktop-site"></nav>
           <ul class="navi-level-1">
                    <li class="has-sub p1"><a>Home<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="navi-level-2 ">
                            <li><a href="#" >Tes1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >Tes2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">More +</a></li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                    
                        <li class="has-sub p1"><a>Contact Us<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

                        <ul class="navi-level-2 ">
                            <li><a href="#" >Email</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" >More +</a></li>
                        
                        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<div class=navi-right sizzle1601118057090=[object Object]>

                <div title="library" class="circle-wrapper">
                    <div class="lib circle"></div>
                    <div class="icon">
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why this happens after deployment do you have any idea about this issue

Comment: IE is old outdated browser, and never was a good one. Any problems with IE are IE cases. Please use different browser - if you work on win7 better browsers are still available. Use https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/ too, and clarify your question - is this browser or code problem?

Comment: I have tested the page in Chrome, Edge and firefox. it is working fine. I faced this issue only with IE @blackblue

Comment: This must be IE indolence or IE bug. Test please with mentioned w3c validator and provide results into your question. Do you have any hack for IE7 etc or any new feature in css? (float, flex, grid,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<header>` and `<nav>` are both HTML5 tags and are only supported by IE 9+.

I guess you view the page in **compatibility view** in IE after you deploy it to server. Please check the document mode emulated in F12 dev tools to see if it's below IE 9. I can reproduce your issue with IE emulated version below 9:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZNl3.png]

Please remove the site from the compatibility view sites list or add the below meta tag in your code, then try to check the page again in IE 11:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Reference:

[`<nav>` Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav#Browser_compatibility)

[`<header>` Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I have tried to add it, this is what I needed exactly. now it is working perfectly in IE as well thank you very much